# How to understand FOR UPDATE OF my_table?

Tags: postgresql, locking, select-for-update

I use Spring Data Jpa to work with the Postgres database. When accessing the database, the following query is generated:

```
select
    user0_.user_id as user_id1_0_,
    user0_.birthday as birthday2_0_,
    user0_.username as username3_0_ 
from
    users user0_ 
where
    user0_.username=$1
limit $2
for update of user0_ skip locked
```

Examples on the Internet usually indicate that columns are specified after `for update of`, but a table is specified here in the query. What will be blocked in this case? The whole row?

Comment: If the random internet examples you have seen indicate for updating column name, then they were not for Postgres. The Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) format shows *for update of **table_name***. Further it goes on to state *FOR UPDATE ... the SELECT statement locks the selected rows*.  Since an update in Postgres is essentially a `delete then insert` operation it seems that is required.  You will always do better referring to the documentation than anywhere else.

Comment: @Belayer, yes, I saw the documentation. But I didn’t find any difference between `select for update skip locked` and `select for update of table_name skip locked` My question about this.

Comment: In addition, `FOR UPDATE` is the correct lock only if you plan to delete the row or update a key column. Otherwise, you should use `FOR NO KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `FROM` clause only includes a single table (`users AS user0_` in the example), there is effectively no difference between `FOR UPDATE OF user0_` and simply `FOR UPDATE`. But it makes a difference with multiple tables in the `FROM` clause.
[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) explains in depth:

> If specific tables are named in a locking clause, then only rows
> coming from those tables are locked; any other tables used in the
> `SELECT` are simply read as usual. A locking clause without a table
> list affects all tables used in the statement. If a locking clause is
> applied to a view or sub-query, it affects all tables used in the view
> or sub-query. However, these clauses do not apply to `WITH` queries
> referenced by the primary query. If you want row locking to occur
> within a `WITH` query, specify a locking clause within the `WITH`
> query.

And no, you cannot list columns there in Postgres. Only tables. Postgres locks selected rows with this clause. Not columns.